# Geocoding: Can you only use it for contacts?

Tags: contacts, civicase, geocoding

I want to use Geocoding on Cases. My cases have specific locations and I would like to input an address and then use Geocoding. Can this be done?
Thanks

Comment: You mean you would attach custom fields to the cases for this information?

Comment: Guessing he means he would add custom Lat/Long fields but wants Geocoding to fill them based on a set of other custom fields that he uses for the address for the Case

Comment: which cms is this?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a situation where the Case is related to a house/building site and hence you want to be able to map 'all cases' then getting Address fields and Lat/Long fields would take significant coding I think.

Workarounds? If you already have an Organisation Contact sub-type to represent the dwelling then you can get the Lat/Long for that and hence create the map filtering on those which have current Cases.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I will try the workaround today - hopefully I can try and map that way. Thanks again - really helpful!

Comment: how are you mapping - just civi profile?